# Payment Gateway module in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke-module

I have done an interswitch payment gateway in my regular asp.net webform and asp.net mvc.

But I have a requirement to do the same in dotnetnuke which i know i can through module.

In my pay now pay of my application i have a form to send data across to interswitch webservice the form is below

```
<form name="form1" action="https://stageserv.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/pay"
method="post">
    <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="XX" />
    <input name="pay_item_id" type="hidden" value="XX" />
    <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="XXXXXXX" />
    <input name="currency" type="hidden" value="566" />
    <input name="site_redirect_url" type="hidden" value="http://abc.com /getresponse”/>
   <input name="txn_ref" type="hidden" value=" XXXAFTXXX”" />
<input name="hash" type="hidden" value="BB292DF9268F05CB9CBBC5E0C13CC1B13ACA34DC" />
</form>
```

I need someone to help me out on how i can implement this in my dotnetnukes module.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and asked this question. [The accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897404/best-way-to-create-and-post-a-form-in-codebehind-in-c-sharp) is how I ended up doing it.

I just added the input fields to the page and then changed the "Pay" buttons `PostBackUrl`

This way you don't need to add an additional form to the page, and when the user clicks the button, it will submit those fields, so obviously it will pick up the ones it's looking for.

**So in your case it would be:**

```
<%-- other page content before --%>

<input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="XX" />
<input name="pay_item_id" type="hidden" value="XX" />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="XXXXXXX" />
<input name="currency" type="hidden" value="566" />
<input name="site_redirect_url" type="hidden" value="http://ipsum.com/getresponse”/>
<input name="txn_ref" type="hidden" value=" XXXAFTXXX”" />
<input name="hash" type="hidden" value="BB292DF9268F05CB9CBBC5E0C13CC1B13ACA34DC" />

<%-- pay button would look like this --%>
<asp:Button ID="btnPayNow" runat="server" PostBackUrl="https://stageserv.interswitchng.com/test_paydirect/pay" Text="Pay Now!" />

<%-- other page content after --%>
```

Of course if you have multiple payment gateway options you can set the `PostBackUrl` programatically before you display the form: `btnPayNow.PostBackUrl = "http://<url>.com"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to another site, not even anything on your site then you don't need a module at all.

With DNN you cannot include another form on your site like that. But you could make that a .html page and include that on your site as an iframe or something like that.

That should post to that other service fine.