# Best way to create and post a form in codebehind in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, code-behind

I'm using webforms and I need to create and `POST` an http `form` to a payment gateway for one of my clients. I'm using a user control that is displayed in a masterpage, however they already have an existing `<form>` on the page, so I'm pretty sure I cannot add another.

What is the best practice method to create and post a form in C# from the code behind? Currently I have the following:

```
var nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
    {
        {"EWAY_ACCESSCODE", ewayResponse.AccessCode},
        {"EWAY_CARDNAME", txtCcName.Text},
        {"EWAY_CARDNUMBER", txtCcNumber.Text},
        {"EWAY_CARDEXPIRYMONTH", ddlCcExpMonth.SelectedValue},
        {"EWAY_CARDEXPIRYYEAR", ddlCcExpYear.SelectedValue},
        {"EWAY_CARDCVN", txtCcv.Text}
    };

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadValues(ewayResponse.FormActionURL, nvc);
```

**This does work, but is there a better / alternative way to do it?**

Comment: cooooooooooooooo, this might give some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the previous suggestion:

- why wouldn't a (simpler) [Button.PostbackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx) work?

  ```
  <asp:Button ID="externalPost" runat="server" PostBackUrl="http://www.somewhere.com/" Text="Post Somewhere" />
  ```

Also, assuming that's a payment gateway you're referring to, you're doing a server-side POST, which has implications on *PCI Compliance* (vs. a direct form post from client/browser).

Hth.

Comment: I agree with the PCI stuff, that's why I'd like to do find a better solution. So the best option would be IrishChieftain's solution? Or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: @AlexFrame As above, any reason why `Button.PostBackUrl` wouldn't work? What it will do is actually do a direct post to the url you set, resolving the PCI matter. I haven't tried the suggestion below, but a quick read of the code allows you to remove the server-side `<form/>` tag. Of course, that would also mean that some other code maybe affected (e.g. other controls on page that rely on default Postback behavior), which you will then need to adjust.

Comment: It "toggles" the form tag so no other controls are affected. I used it in five different E-Commerce sites I have developed. You can use JavaScript presuming it's enabled on all clients. Only other solution is to add a second pair of form tags and that's a hack that nobody has yet explained ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I use:

http://jerschneid.blogspot.com/2007/03/hide-form-tag-but-leave-content.html

Caveat (own blog post):

http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/08/Solution-to-ASPNET-Form-PayPal-Problem.aspx